# how to align multiple <h1> tags

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make a header with a title in the center "Resources", left another title "HTML" and right another with "CSS" but I can not align them to put them in the right place and then add a border-right and border-left to separate the left and right title from the title to the center.

For the moment I have this:

```css
header {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1.html {
  padding-left: 2%;
}

h1.res {}

h1.css {
  padding-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="html">HTML</h1>
  <h1 class="res">Ressources</h1>
  <h1 class="css">CSS</h1>
</header>
```

Because of the display: inline-block; it works better but I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be simpler to replace the `<h1>` tags with `<span>` elements because they are `inline` by default. The left and right separation can be accomplished several ways. See example below.

```css
.header {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  color:white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.header span:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
}

.header span:nth-child(3) {
  float: right;
  width: 33%;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class='header'>
  <span>HTML</span>
  <span>RESOURCES</span>
  <span>CSS</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flex layout to position the headings. Add this to your existing `header` ruleset:

```
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```